# MS Project Server 2013 and Sharepoint 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sharepoint-2010, project-server

I want to know, can I write an ASP.Net app which use Project Server 2013 API and includes it as a webpart on Sharepoint 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can providing the Project Server 2013 libraries are stored on the GAC or alternatively on the bin folder if you set the required CAS permissions

Answer (score 1):

Your question is short on details, but the answer is yes.